# RecyclerView Scroll hang inside NestedScrollView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

`RecyclerView` Scroll hang when I put inside `NestedScrollView` it work if set `recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)`  but problem is if i set `recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)` then `RecyclerView` Adapter `onViewAttachedToWindow(ViewHolder holder)` and `onViewDetachedFromWindow(ViewHolder holder)` method not called and also `onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position)` not called when scroll  the list.

My HeaderView is More Complex so I unable to add as header in `RecyclerView` so I put it in `NestedScrollView`

How can I use This two method when `RecyclerView` is Inside `NestedScrollView`

```
@Override
public void onViewAttachedToWindow(ViewHolder holder) {
    super.onViewAttachedToWindow(holder);
}

@Override
public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(ViewHolder holder) {
    super.onViewDetachedFromWindow(holder);
}
```

Below is my code;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/nested_scrollview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Activity Code

```
    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

    //recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    TMPAdapter adapter = new TMPAdapter(this, strings);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Adapter Code

```
public class TMPAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TMPAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private static final String TAG = LogUtils.makeLogTag(TMPAdapter.class);
private List<String> mListValue;
private Context mContext;

public TMPAdapter(Context context, List<String> listValue) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mListValue = listValue;
}

@Override
public void onViewAttachedToWindow(ViewHolder holder) {
    super.onViewAttachedToWindow(holder);
}

@Override
public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(ViewHolder holder) {
    super.onViewDetachedFromWindow(holder);
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item_like_list, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.mTxtUserName.setText(mListValue.get(position));

}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return super.getItemId(position);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mListValue.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private VeniTextView mTxtUserName;

    ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        mTxtUserName = view.findViewById(R.id.txt_user_name);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: i am face same problems